# How to set product fees displayed only for a country in curent language that user is using

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, country

I'm using a plugin "WooCommerce Product Fees" to add custom fees to products. I want to set these custom fields to be displayed only for one country.

```
     * Check if a product contains fee data.
     *
     * @param int $id Product ID.
     * @return bool True or false based on existance of custom meta.
     */
    public function product_contains_fee_data( $id ) {
        $fee_name   = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-name', true );
        $fee_amount = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-amount', true );

        if ( '' !== $fee_name && '' !== $fee_amount && $fee_amount > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

/////////////////**
     * Get all the fees.
     *
     * @param object $cart WC Cart object.
     * @return array $fees An array of fees to be added.
     */
    public function get_fees( $cart ) {
        $fees = array();

        if ( $this->maybe_remove_fees_for_coupon( $cart ) ) {
            return $fees;
        }

        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item => $item ) {

            // Get the data we need from each product in the cart.
            $item_data = array(
                'id'           => $item['data']->get_id(),
                'variation_id' => $item['variation_id'],
                'parent_id'    => $item['data']->get_parent_id(),
                'qty'          => $item['quantity'],
                'price'        => $item['data']->get_price()
            );

            $fee = $this->get_fee_data( $item_data );

            if ( $fee ) {
                $fee_id        = strtolower( $fee['name'] );
                $fee_tax_class = $this->get_fee_tax_class( $item['data'] );

                if ( array_key_exists( $fee_id, $fees ) && 'combine' === get_option( 'wcpf_name_conflicts', 'combine' ) ) {
                    $fees[$fee_id]['amount'] += $fee['amount'];
                } else {
                    $fees[$fee_id] = apply_filters( 'wcpf_filter_fee_data', array(
                        'name' => $fee['name'],
                        'amount' => $fee['amount'],
                        'taxable' => ( '_no_tax' === $fee_tax_class ) ? false : true,
                        'tax_class' => $fee_tax_class
                    ), $item_data );
                }
            }
        }

        return $fees;
    }
```

What I want to accomplish is that this field must show only if the user is from one country, so on product page must not display for a country either on cart and checkout. Is there a filter that can I add to exclude this field from one country?
Thank you in advance!!!

** UPDATE**

I'm trying to dispaly the translation for the "$fee_name" in curent language that the user is using. Now my site is in greek and english and I'm using wpml but this field isn't translating. I was thinking if is a way to add the ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE and str_replace somehow so if the user is using the site in english to see the "$fee_name" translated.( but it brokes the site ).
 This is my code:

```
        $fee_name   = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-name', true );
        $fee_amount = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-amount', true );
        $fee_name_en = str_replace('product-fee-name', 'Recycling   Tax', $fee_name); 
        $country_code = 'GR'; // <=== Set the country code
        $user_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(); // or with get_billing_country(); method too.

        if( '' !== $fee_name_en && '' !== $fee_amount && $fee_amount > 0  && $user_country === $country_code && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') {

            return true;}


        else ( '' !== $fee_name && '' !== $fee_amount && $fee_amount > 0  && $user_country === $country_code && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='el') {

            return true;

            }



        return false;
    }
```

I really appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following in your first function:

```
public function product_contains_fee_data( $id ) {
    $fee_name   = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-name', true );
    $fee_amount = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-amount', true );

    $country_code = 'FR'; // <=== Set the country code
    $user_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(); // or with get_billing_country(); method too.

    if ( '' !== $fee_name && '' !== $fee_amount && $fee_amount > 0  && $user_country === $country_code ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It should work.